# Yawing during turns

Tags: aircraft-physics, flight-dynamics, yaw

This is a question about aeronautics. Does an airplane yaw while it is turning?

Comment: If it doesn't yaw then the nose points always in the same direction. If it has turn, say, 180° then it has yawn 180°

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Can you please clarify what exactly you are asking about? Are you talking about [adverse yaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_yaw)?

Comment: Perhaps OP asks if rudder input is given...

Comment: "Yaw" is used in several different ways in aviation.  In the strictest sense of the word, your question would appear to be essentially "when an aircraft is turning, is the *yaw rate* other than zero?"  Is this what you mean?  And if so, how could it not be?

Comment: Rolling vs. yawing, and ailerons use vs. rudder use are explained in [Are the functions of ailerons and rudder similar?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24101/3201), as well as what is a coordinated turn.

Answer (score 1):

> Does an airplane yaw while it is turning?

Not always.

A turn is a curvature in the flight path.

Imagine we initiate a bank to the left in a sailplane, without touching the rudder.

As the aircraft rolls left, the nose will swing (yaw) to the right due to *adverse yaw*, and the *yaw string* will deflect to the right.

As the left bank angle increases, in most (but not all) gliders at some point the lateral force from the banked wing will overcome the opposing sideforce from the airflow hitting the side of the fuselage, and the flight path will start curving to the left.

As the left bank continues to increase, at some point the aircraft's inherent "*weathervane stability*" will act to prevent the sideslip angle (i.e. the yaw string deflection angle) from becoming any larger.  If the sideslip angle (i.e. the yaw string deflection angle) is not increasing, and the flight path is curving to the left, the aircraft must also now be yawing to the left, not to the right.

At some instant in time before the sideslip angle stopped increasing, it must have been the case that the sideslip angle was still increasing, but at a rate that exactly matched the increasing rate of leftwards curvature in the flight path.  At that moment in time, the aircraft's heading must have been momentarily constant.  At that moment in time, the aircraft was yawing neither to the right nor to the left.
So at that moment in time, the aircraft was turning without yawing.

A simpler (but less often-seen, except at airshows) case of turning without yawing is a 90-degree-banked "knife edge" turn, with the pilot holding top rudder so that the airflow strikes the earthward side of the fuselage and supports the aircraft's weight.  Some yaw rotation was involved in *establishing* the "knife-edge" attitude, but once it is established, the aircraft can fly around in circles indefinitely without any rotation about the yaw axis.

Comment: +1:  Making the distinction between *Yaw* and *Sideslip* is important.  I would perhaps have made this point a bit more emphatically. Perhaps "Yaw" string is a misnomer. It should probably better be called a "Sideslip" string.